# Getting PROPFIND in apache access logs

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am getting lots of request in my apache access log file as follows:

```
50.80.29.105 - - [19/Sep/2012:07:32:31] "PROPFIND /images/logos/puzzles.gif HTTP/1.1" 501 5014
```

Because of this error is getting generated on my server; and log files are getting filled up with exceptions. Is there a way to avoid this ? Probably put it in robots.txt !

Answer (score 1):

block `Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir`, and add a generic block for `any UA using: WebDAV` , as this is a method used by WebDAV , mostly by an org who is trying to improve its rankings.

Add these lines to [Directory] section of httpd.conf , save it and restart Apache:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ^Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir BegoneWebDAV
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from env=BegoneWebDAV
```

Comment: I do have httpd.conf. I did made changes like this in my VirtualHost configurations : <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  <Directory>
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ^Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir BegoneWebDAV
                Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from env=BegoneWebDAV
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
 but it failed.

Comment: remove the lines that I said from apache.conf, and remove the following files from $APACHE_HOME/mods-enabled/  dav.load/dav_fs.conf/dav_fs.load/dav_lock.load  , then restart apache.